# How to host an AP or a hotspot?

Tags: wireless, apt, iptables, hostapd

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine on my Mac. Since I am unable to get the virtual machine to have full access to my WiFi card, I bought another USB WiFi card to use.

[This is my WiFi card.](http://www.airlink101.com/support/index.php?cmd=files&id=178)

If you are unfamiliar with Virtual machine, as far as I know, since the Ubuntu has its own card now, it shouldn't matter.

I have followed these guides with no luck:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint
- http://www.danbishop.org/2011/12/11/using-hostapd-to-add-wireless-access-point-capabilities-to-an-ubuntu-server/

The problem is that the WiFi connection appears on all of the machines that I have in my house: 2 iPhones, Dell machine running Ubuntu and two Macbooks. However the connection times out on all of these machines.

Questions:

1. Could this be a driver issue if that same WiFi card can connect to other WiFi points and use its internet
2. Could this be DHCP related? I would think not. It should at least get a 169.X.X.X address? No?
3. Any solutions for me?

Comment: Sorry to jump on the "me too" but this affects me too- I'd love to be able to get the ad-hoc wireless network up and running from my Ubuntu installation!

Comment: Well, let me know if you wanna work on this together. If you want, you can jump on irc freenode room #joubin and we can hammer it our together. (IE compare notes/errors) L

Comment: does your Wi-fi card support AP & Master mode? The link u have posted giving sql-database error. Any way, first type `sudo iwconfig`, this  should list all available wireless interfaces. `sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode master` & replace wlan1 with your interface.

Comment: Also you need to check what kernel driver you are using.To do this first type `lspci | grep -i wireless`. Take the first number it prints & type: `lspci -vv -s 03:00.0`  replace `03:00.0` with ur number. At the end of the output it wiil show something like this `Kernel modules: ath9k`. This means your kaernel driver is `ath9k`. You can type `modinfo ath9k`.This again produces lots of information which may require for debugging.

Comment: There is `depends:` section which shows something like this :`depends: ath9k_hw,mac80211,led-class,ath,cfg80211,ath9k_common`. nl80211/cfg80211 (most new drivers) are well supported by linux.

Comment: The kernel driver that the wireless card is using can be found with this one-line command: `lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "network"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog you are following doesn't list general steps of setting up wifi-ap with hostapd.
For 12.04 more complete step by step details can be found here:

[wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu](http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/)

The detailed step-by-step answer is already posted here at Ask-Ubuntu:

[**How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can check by opening  **addtional drivers** in dash whether it is need or not. If your system missing it , it will automatically indicate it and suggest to install.

According to me , It may problem of DHCP server , Configure your router dhcp , give long lease time in configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

On W8 website there is a new script for this purposes, very easy and comfortable.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

Working good on my laptop.