# Trying to share internet on non-AdHoc WiFi, not working

Tags: wireless, networking, android

The usual situation: Android phones don't like ad-hoc networks, so I'm trying to make Ubuntu act as hotspot with a non-ad-hoc network instead.

I'm on a fresh install of whatever version of Ubuntu the official download page gave me.

I started by following this [How do I create a non-adhoc wifi hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105217/how-do-i-create-a-non-adhoc-wifi-hotspot) guide, but it doesn't work.

( When I run `iwconfig` I get `eth1` instead of `wlan0` as my WiFi, so I've replaced `wlan0` with `eth1` in all the instructions in the link above. And I've had to do `sudo apt-get install hostapd` to get `hostapd`, but that seems to have worked)

When I do `sudo hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` I get

`nl80211: Failed to set interface eth1 into AP mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
ELOOP: remaining socket: sock=4 eloop_data=0x8413900 user_data=0x8413ea8 handler=0x807c5e0
ELOOP: remaining socket: sock=6 eloop_data=0x8416420 user_data=(nil) handler=0x8086770`

This is my first time trying to set anything up in a linux environment, so I have no idea what's going wrong or where to look for clues as to how to proceed.

---

Just now, I noticed this [Failed to set interface wlan0 into AP mode: Intel centrino N1000 Wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319838/failed-to-set-interface-wlan0-into-ap-mode-intel-centrino-n1000-wireless) in the list to the right of where I'm typing this question.

I did the `sudo iwconfig eth1 mode master.` (is the period supposed to be there? tried without, same result) and got

`Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device eth1 ; Invalid argument.`

and there's no `AP` in the list of supported modes. Does this mean I'm doomed?

---

Trying to dig further on my own, I found http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/ and at one point it tells me to run `lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "network"`, from which I find `Kernel driver in use: ipw2200`, which when input in the next command `modinfo ipw2200 | grep 'depend'` gives me `depends: cfg80211,libipw,lib80211`. This does not include `mac80211` which is the one specifically mentioned in the link as supported. I have not been able to figure out if any of the ones I do get are supported or not.