# wifi hotspot configuration

Tags: wireless, networking

I was trying to activate network sharing on my computer and I had this error message from the terminal

```
Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode.
```

My wireless card info is as follows

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 35
   serial: 00:27:10:80:db:30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-29-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn"
```

I am not a comp guru but can follow instructions very well, please help.

Comment: See this: http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

Answer (score 3):

Answered very nicely [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319838/failed-to-set-interface-wlan0-into-ap-mode-intel-centrino-n1000-wireless) already,

To use your network card as wifi hotspot, it must support `AP` mode & `master` mode.

To check `master-mode` run:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master.
```

If you dont get a error then it supports master-mode

To check `AP` run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install iw
```

Then run:

```
iw list
```

If there is 'AP' in the list of "Supported interface modes" your device will support the Access Point mode with hostapd.

But as you explained above, that it **doesn't support** `AP` mode, The wifi hotspot wont work as explained in the blog.

Unlike windows, linux-kernel doesn't provide same features for every wireless cards.So for a particular wifi-card, windows driver may support AP , but linux-driver may not.

One option is to purchase a wireless card which supports AP modes.