# How to solve adapter does not support AP (master) mode problem?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I have intel centrino N1000 wireless card. I am able to setup "wifi hotspot" with windows 7. But I am not able to setup "wifi hotspot" in ubuntu though I am able to connect to other wifi devices and use internet. I have earlier set "wifi hotspot" with ubuntu but now it throws the error, "Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode"

Comment: :( read this >>[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/477057/wifi-hotspot-configuration