# Hostap: wlan0 authentication timed out

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point, hostapd, ath9k

I have made a PC an Access Point using the following link:

https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd

But whenever I connect to the AP my kernel prints the following error:

```
wlan0: authentication with e8:de:27:0b:93:bb timed out
```

The kernel version is Ubuntu 3.13.2 and running Ubuntu 14.04.3 32 bit PC. Hostapd version is 1.0-3.

Comment: FYI. 14.04.3 is the Ubuntu release version. You can obtain the kernel version from the output of `uname -r`

Comment: The kernel version is 3.13.2.

Comment: [edit]ed into your question

Comment: Have you reviewed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/319838/failed-to-set-interface-wlan0-into-ap-mode-intel-centrino-n1000-wireless?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify only the relevant authentication options in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256
```

If this doesn't work, run the daemon by hand in debug mode to see where isn't working:

```
hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Comment: We are not using any authentication algorithm.